# Best possible quality setting for screen recording (not games) and web presentation

Tags: compression, h.264, screen-casting, handbrake

1. Screen videos have text and simple geometric shapes, which need to
   stay sharp, detailed and crispy. The color should also remain
   untouched. With screen grabs, I want e.g. IBM blue to show as IBM blue
   in the final MP4. Smoothness of animations is also very important
2. The requirements are different from regular video, but so is the
   source material. Except UI animations, the frames are mostly still

Since I need to show these videos on a web site, my compression is based on h.264/avc. Can anybody suggest a set of parameters or offer some tips?

What have I tried? So far the most acceptable results were with variable frame rate, file size being 1/2 of the original (540x960), bit rate up to 3Mbps. I used encoder level 4 (probably should have used 3 for better compatibility?) and Profile set to Best. I tried Apple Compressor and Handbrake.